# Square root from parameter passing during the run

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I'm newbie in `C/C++` languages and I want to ask one simple question. I've written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    printf("Square root from %f is %f", argv[1], sqrt(argv[1]));
}
```

But it doesn't work because argv[1] has type `char*`. How can I cast `argv[1]` to double and if it's impossible throw an exception?

Comment: You want to parse a string, not do a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [atof](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof). Therefore, you would be writing something like this:

```
printf("Square root from %s is %f", argv[1], sqrt(atof(argv[1])));
```

Of course, you could look into higher-level alternatives like C++11's [std::stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/), but it would be an overkill for this simple case, but if you insist on using C++ code later, I would write this if I were you:

```
std::string myString = argv[1];
std::cout << "Square root from " << argv[1] << " is "
          << std::sqrt(std::stod(myString)) << std::endl;
```

You would also need to change the first placeholder to `%s` because you are printing the first argument in there, which is as you wrote a string.

In your final code, please also make sure that `argc` is at least 2 before trying to access the second item of the string array.

Comment: And note that the first `%f` needs to be changed to `%s`. And maybe change the second one to `%lf` since you get a double.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ `"%f"` and `"%lf"` do the same thing with `printf()`.

Comment: It'll give a warning, won't it?